# Using for loop to create variables in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dynamic, dynamic-variables, dynamic-values

I need to create 50 different variables named "A1,A2,...A49,A50". Each variable will receive the value of an operation, like in the example below:

```
a = 10
b = 6
for x in range(50)
    A%x = a+b
    a=a+5
    b=b+5
```

I put the "A%n" just to show (as an example) of what I am looking for, that I want the variable name to change at each iteration of the for loop.

I don't how to do that. Can anyone help me?
Thank you very much

Comment: See the duplicate, but short answer: don't. Use a dict or a list.

Comment: Thank you, that helped